# How to incorporate a popup window when selecting a child in an expandable list

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, actionbarsherlock, expandablelistview, popupwindow

Here's a pretty cookie cutter program that expands a list, and then when you click a child, it pops a message saying, "Child Clicked". But I want the expandable list to consists of recipes so that when clicked, it shows a popup window of the ingredients. I tried making it an arraylist of objects instead of strings, and having the objects contain the list of ingredients, but I got all tangled up when trying to display the ingredients.. Thanks in advance!

```
package com.poe.poeguide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;

public class Recipes extends SherlockActivity {
private ExpandableListView mExpandableList;

 /** An array of strings to populate dropdown list */
String[] actions = new String[] {
   "Recipes",
   "Main Page",
   "Attributes",
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipes);

    /** Create an array adapter to populate dropdownlist */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, actions);

    /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    /** Defining Navigation listener */
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
            switch(itemPosition) {
            case 0:

                break;
            case 1:
                Intent a = new Intent(Recipes.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);



    mExpandableList = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);

    ArrayList<Parent> arrayParents = new ArrayList<Parent>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayChildren = new ArrayList<String>();

    //======================================================================================
    //here we set the parents and the children
        //for each "i" create a new Parent object to set the title and the children
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setTitle("Pies");
        arrayChildren.add("Apple Pie ");
        arrayChildren.add("Blueberry Pie ");
        parent.setArrayChildren(arrayChildren);

        //in this array we add the Parent object. We will use the arrayParents at the setAdapter
        arrayParents.add(parent);

    //======================================================================================

    //sets the adapter that provides data to the list.
    mExpandableList.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(Recipes.this,arrayParents));

    mExpandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, int arg3, long arg4)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Child clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_recipes, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we begin, note that `Recipes` is a confusing name for an Activity. I would highly recommend changing the name to follow the standard convention of ending with the word "Activity" (e.g., `RecipeActivity`).

---

First you need to create a `Recipe` object so you can store the name and ingredients together. This object can be as simple or as complex as you need, but let's pretend it looks something like this:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Recipe {
    private String name;
    private List<String> ingredients;
    private List<String> directions;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // By default, the Adapter classes in Android will call toString() on
        // your object to figure out how it should appear in lists. To make sure
        // the list displays the recipe name, we return the recipe name here.
        return name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public void setIngredients(List<String> ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }

    public List<String> getDirections() {
        return directions;
    }

    public void setDirections(List<String> directions) {
        this.directions = directions;
    }
}
```

Notice that we override `toString()` for this object and return the recipe name. This way, when we ask our adapter class to display a list of `Recipe` objects, it knows what text should be shown for each item in the list.

---

When creating the data for your list, instead of:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayChildren = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Use:

```
List<Recipe> arrayChildren = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
```

*(Note: You might need to modify the `Parent` class to take `List<Recipe>` or the generic `List<?>` for the children if that field is only accepting `List<String>` right now.)*

Let's add one sample `Recipe` object:

```
Recipe salsa = new Recipe();
salsa.setName("Pineapple Salsa");
salsa.setIngredients(Arrays.asList("pineapple", "cilantro", "lime", "jalapeno"));
salsa.setDirections(Arrays.asList("Blend ingredients and enjoy"));
arrayChildren.add(salsa);
```

Now that your list is backed by `Recipe` objects instead of just strings, it's simply a matter of getting that object when a list item is clicked. Here's how you might do this:

```
mExpandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        // Get the selected recipe
        Recipe recipe = (Recipe) parent.getExpandableListAdapter()
                .getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        // Build a string listing the ingredients
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("Ingredients:\n");
        for (String ingredient : recipe.getIngredients())
            message.append("\n").append(ingredient);

        // Display a dialog listing the ingredients
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MyGreatHelloWorldActivity.this)
                .setTitle(recipe.getName()).setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Yum!", null).show();

        // Return true because we handled the click
        return true;
    }
});
```

---

**Update:** Here's how you can complete the task with a no-frills adapter for expandable lists.

I created a generic class called `ExpandableListGroup` *(equivalent to your `Parent` class)* to hold the children. The class is generic so it will work with any kind of objects, but we'll use it with `Recipe` objects.

```
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableListGroup<T> {
    private String name;
    private List<T> children;

    public ExpandableListGroup(String name, List<T> children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<T> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<T> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then I created the following generic `ExpandableListArrayAdapter` class:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListArrayAdapter<T> extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private List<ExpandableListGroup<T>> groups;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ExpandableListArrayAdapter(Context context,
            List<ExpandableListGroup<T>> groups) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ExpandableListGroup<T> group = getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, parent,
                    false);
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) convertView;
        text.setText(group.toString());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        T item = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, parent,
                    false);
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) convertView;
        text.setText(item.toString());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public T getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).getChildren().size();
    }

    @Override
    public ExpandableListGroup<T> getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, here's how you tie it all together:

```
// Create one list per group
List<Recipe> appetizers = new ArrayList<Recipe>(),
        desserts = new ArrayList<Recipe>();

// TODO: Create Recipe objects and add to lists

List<ExpandableListGroup<Recipe>> groups = Arrays.asList(
        new ExpandableListGroup<Recipe>("Appetizers", appetizers),
        new ExpandableListGroup<Recipe>("Desserts", desserts));
mExpandableList.setAdapter(new ExpandableListArrayAdapter<Recipe>(this,
        groups));
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response. It's a little advanced though. Do you think you could show some sample code for the next steps I would take? Should I make a separate java class file, what should I put in it?

Comment: Do I need to make a custom adapter class? Mine got all messed up when I tried to match the corresponding changes. Can I just use the default Android adapter?

Comment: @user1787038 If this were a `ListView`, then, no, you could simply use `ArrayAdapter`. However, there's no equivalent for an `ExpandableListView`. You're only "default" adapter option for an expandable list is `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`, which isn't very simple at all, so you're going to be better off with a custom adapter. I've updated my answer to provide an example of this.

Comment: Once I create a Recipe object, how do I add it to the the list?

Comment: @user1787038 With `appetizers.add(salsa)`